# Cyanogenmod Profile Issues

Tags: cyanogenmod, reboot, profiles

Every time I reboot my phone new profiles are created and existing ones lose all settings. For example restart my phone 3 times I will have 3 profiles of each default one all with no settings. Anyone else have this problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: What version of CyanogenMod is this? If you're on a nightly then it could just be a bug, and you might want to consider reporting it to the developers.

Comment: @eldarerathis CyanogenMod 11 stable build